# Badmatch error when doing XRestackWindows

Tags: linux, unix, x11

I have created 2 windows. Window A is a window that has a 32 bit color depth and Window B that has a 24 bit color depth. Window B is created with A as the parent. I want to restack the windows such that Window A is always above Window B, however by running this snippet, it tells me that it gives me an error and tells me it's a bad match. In my case opengl_window is window A and gstreamer_window is window B.

```
Window windows[2] = {opengl_window, gstreamer_window};
XRestackWindows(x_display, windows, 2);
```

Here is how I created the windows.

```
int nxvisuals = 0;
XVisualInfo visual_template;
XVisualInfo *visual_list;
XVisualInfo vinfo;
Visual *visual;
int depth;

/* Open the standard display (the primary screen) */
x_display = XOpenDisplay ( NULL );
if ( x_display == NULL )
{
    return 1;
}

visual_template.screen = DefaultScreen(x_display);
visual_list = XGetVisualInfo(x_display, VisualScreenMask, &visual_template, &nxvisuals);

if (!XMatchVisualInfo(x_display, XDefaultScreen(x_display), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo))
{
    return 1;
}

parent = XDefaultRootWindow(x_display);
XSync(x_display, True);
visual = vinfo.visual;
depth = vinfo.depth;

XSetWindowAttributes  swa;
swa.event_mask = ExposureMask | PointerMotionMask | KeyPressMask;
swa.colormap = XCreateColormap(x_display, XDefaultRootWindow(x_display), visual, AllocNone);
swa.background_pixel = 0;
swa.border_pixel = 0;

/* Create a window */
opengl_window = XCreateWindow (
          x_display, parent,
          0, 0, m_plane_width, m_plane_height, 0,
          depth, InputOutput,
          visual, CWEventMask | CWBackPixel | CWColormap | CWBorderPixel,
          &swa );
```

Similarly I created the gstreamer window with the same thing except this line is changed to 24.

```
if (!XMatchVisualInfo(x_display, XDefaultScreen(x_display), 24, TrueColor, &vinfo))
{
    return 1;
}
```

My exact error is:

```
Start laptop loading file handle 12
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  12 (X_ConfigureWindow)
  Serial number of failed request:  32
  Current serial number in output stream:  32
[Inferior 1 (process 2232) exited with code 01]
```

Comment: It doesn't work this way. You can only restack siblings. A child window is not above or below its parent, it makes no sense to say that.